# Improve fedoras performance

Tags: linux, performance, fedora

I'm using Fedora and day by day my system's performance gets worse.

Can anyone tell me what might be causing this and how can I fix it.

Comment: System spec?, RAM? Running apps? More info would be great

Answer (score 2):

Install the [fedora package](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/atop?_csrf_token=d407477b8879d688b972dae4763cc81ac8c5db4f) of [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/) and run it from the commandline.

This program will show what the (hardware) bottleneck is in your system.
The hardware that has an heavy load will show in red.

Press "D" to show which processes are accessing the disk, maybe a service you don't use is degrading disk performance.

Answer (score -1):

Before the edit, you mentioned a concern about temp files.

Temp file are often deleted when a system is rebooted.

I don't know if this applies to Fedora, but you should try rebooting, if you haven't already.

Another explanation may be that the HDD is slowly failing, such that retries following *seek* operations are becoming more common.